# Create a matrix from text file -java

Tags: java, matrix

I have a text file that have data at this format:

```
word:filename:wordCount
```

I wanna create a matrix that have the values as follows:

```
the length of the matrix is same the number of the words in the file
the width is the number of the files.
```

For example:

```
apple:file1:2
apple:file3:4
cat:file1:3
tea:file2:5
ugly:file4:3
```

the length=5
the width=4

I want the output like that:

```
apple:[2,0,4,0]
cat:[3,0,0,0]
tea:[0,5,0,0]
ugle:[0,0,0,3]
```

I try to read the text file then I split the lines by ":"

```
String[] keys = line1.split(":");
```

then I create a two dimentonal array like this:

```
String s[][]=new String[4][4];//the 4=the # of words, 4=number of files
```

I add the 4, because I don't know how to get how many files from the file

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        String h=keys[2];//the word count
        s[i][j]=h;
    }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(s))
```

the output I got is:

```
[[2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2]]
[[4, 4, 4], [4, 4, 4], [4, 4, 4]]
[[3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3]]
[[5, 5, 5], [5, 5, 5], [5, 5, 5]]
[[3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3]]
```

Any help of that please:)

Comment: do you know how many words and files will be there in the input file beforehand? because this is going to be the key to write the solution for your problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: still a problem remains that is - while iterating over all the words, how do you know which word is related to a specific index? say, the word "apple" is mapped to index 0, word "cat" is mapped to index 1 and so on. without having such mapping, you cannot store wordCount in a specific position in the matrix, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

From your preferred output it looks like you're trying to build a map of integer arrays

Here's what I'd do

```
package q42705914;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class Counter {
    private static final int MAX_FILES = 4;
    private final Map<String, int[]> counts = new HashMap<>();

    public Counter() {
        countAll("rawCounts.txt");
        print();
    }

    private void countAll(String filename) {
        try(FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(filename);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader)) {
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                countLine(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private void countLine(String line) {
        String[] parts = line.split(":");

        if(!counts.containsKey(parts[0])) {
            counts.put(parts[0], new int[MAX_FILES]);
        }
        int[] count = counts.get(parts[0]);

        int filenumber = Integer.valueOf(parts[1].substring(4));

        count[filenumber-1] = count[filenumber-1] + Integer.valueOf(parts[2]); 
    }

    private void print() {
        for(Entry<String, int[]> e : counts.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(e.getKey() + ":" + Arrays.toString(e.getValue()));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new Counter();
    }
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question-and-answer site, not a homework writing service.  Please do not give users reason to believe otherwise.  Thank you.

Comment: @mike Thanks alot Mike, I use the code with some modification and it's works.

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems in your code which I am discussing, if that helps you.

1. As you mentioned, `key.length = # of words`, without reading the whole file, how do you know that how many unique words are there? You didn't mention this in your question which makes your question vague!
2. More importantly, `String[] keys = line1.split(":");` should give you `key.length = 3` because your input format is `word:filename:wordCount`.
3. In the inner for loop, `for (int j=0; j<4; j++)` - why are iterating four times? You should rather iterate 3 times, right?

So, the idea should be - going over each line in the file and then iterate through each item in one line separated by `:`.

Try to logically think what you are doing while writing a program!

Comment: Hi Wasi, that's right for point 1 the # of words not same as key.length, I delete it from the question. and for point 3, true I must iterate by 3 because the loop start with zero.